# Cual es la mejor forma de guardar los ajustes de inventarios

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hola a todos estoy realizando un sistema de ventas y tengo una duda que debo hacer o como debo manejar el inventario y los ajustes de inventario?.

ejemplo:

el inventario inicial lo tengo en una tabla que se llama entradas y hay coloco todas las entradas(compras) hasta aquí todo bien, pero cuando se haga un inventario físico
¿como hago ese ajuste?
¿donde lo guardo en otra tabla?

se que debo actualizar las cantidades que tenia en el sistema por las físicas
lo que quiero es lo siguiente
después que se haga ese ajuste se pueda mirar la diferencia entre el inventario anterior y el ajuste de inventario nuevo para mostrar un reporte.

espero me puedan dar una idea de como llevar acabo.

Comment: Esta pregunta seguramente terminará cerrada por basarse en opiniones. Sin embargo, me parece que los ajustes de inventarios son simplemente un tipo de movimiento de entrada o salida según la diferencia del inventario físico con el registrado en el sistema.

Comment: Hola Deimer, obviamente tienes que llevar dos inventarios,el actualizado, y el otro, supongamos que cada quince días haces la comparación, en ese momento copias el actualizado y lo cargas en el otro para efectuar en algún momento una nueva comparación, es solo una idea.

Comment: Muchas formas, si puedes diferenciar entre los tipos de salida, en la misma tabla, sino puedes hacer una solo para ajustes y modificar las existencias, yo me he inclinado en el pasado por esta ultima, lo mejor es que te apoyes con el departamento contable/legal de tu empresa, aunque no lo creas ellos pueden darte una idea, quizás no técnica, pero te ayudará mucho.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder @Luis Cazares ese movimiento de entrada o salida es necesario que quede registrado en alguna parte o solo se actualiza las cantidades?

Comment: Todos los movimientos de entradas y salidas deben de estar registrados y el inventario se puede calcular usando esos movimientos. Eso te permite saber cuanto inventario tenías en un momento dado y no solo el inventario actual.

Comment: muchas gracias por su tiempo